# Copying wav files c++

Tags: c++, file-io, wav, fstream

My program (see below) creates a wav file with the header and so on. I can open it but it does not copy all of the Data chunk. The header is OK: I can open the file with WMP and I can hear some noises but as for Data it does not actually copy all the text. I opened both wav files with Wordpad and the data only collects the first 3 lines of chars then its all spaces (so the Data size is good).

```
fstream ifs(FileInputPath->c_str(), ios_base::in);
cout<< "PATH :" << FileInputPath->c_str()<<endl;
ofstream outfile("C:/Users/miguel/Desktop/proj/Automatic_Visual_Speech_v0.9_beta/exemplo.wav", ofstream::out);
if (ifs.is_open() && outfile.is_open())
{
    char First_Chunk_ID[5]=""; //RIFF
    ifs.read(First_Chunk_ID,4);
    outfile.write(First_Chunk_ID,4);

    long File_Size;  // FileSize
    ifs.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&File_Size), sizeof(long) );
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&File_Size),sizeof(long));

    char Form_Type_ID[5] =""; //Formato
    ifs.read(Form_Type_ID,4);
    outfile.write(Form_Type_ID,4);

    char Second_Chunk_ID[5] = ""; //2ºPedaco
    ifs.read(Second_Chunk_ID,4);
    outfile.write(Second_Chunk_ID,4);

    /*char * charArray_Wave_Format_Size = new char;
    ifs.read(charArray_Wave_Format_Size, sizeof(long));*/

    long Wave_Format_Size; //Tamanho do 2º Pedaço
    ifs.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Wave_Format_Size), sizeof(long) );
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Wave_Format_Size), sizeof(long));

    char Wave_Format_Info[3] = ""; //Tipo de formato!
    ifs.read(Wave_Format_Info, 2);
    outfile.write(Wave_Format_Info,2);

    short NumChannels; //Canais
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&NumChannels),2);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&NumChannels),2);

    long SampleRate;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&SampleRate),4);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&SampleRate),4);

    long ByteRate;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ByteRate),4);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ByteRate),4);

    short BlockAlign;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&BlockAlign),2);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&BlockAlign),2);

    short BitsPerSample;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&BitsPerSample),2);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&BitsPerSample),2);

    char Third_Chunk_ID[5] = "";
    ifs.read(Third_Chunk_ID, 4);
    outfile.write(Third_Chunk_ID,4);

    long charArray_Data_Size;
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&charArray_Data_Size), sizeof(long));
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&charArray_Data_Size),sizeof(long));
            char Data[81600]="";// if you want to read 10000 chars, make a buffer of 10000 chars
    ifs.read(Data,charArray_Data_Size+1);  // use read(), not get().  Everything in the file is binary
    outfile.write(Data,charArray_Data_Size+1);
    outfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you open the output file so I use a psychic guess: You opened your file as text not binary.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream

Comment: Sorry i copy+paste i didn't show up as code, I did like:

 fstream ifs(FileInputPath->c_str(), ios_base::in);
 cout<< "PATH :" << FileInputPath->c_str()<<endl;
 ofstream outfile(PATH, ofstream::out);